# openstack Heat ERROR All heat engines are down

Tags: openstack, heat, openstack-heat

After following this documentation for Installing Heat on ubuntu 20.04 :
https://docs.openstack.org/heat/victoria/install/install-ubuntu.html
I encountered this error :
" ERROR: All heat engines are down. "

Comment: Where did you encounter it? Did you see it on the command line? If so, which command caused it? Or did you find it in a log file? If yes, which log file? Have you searched the error message on the internet? What did you find? Finally, what do you expect from the Stackoverflow community? You did not ask a question.

Comment: thank you for the quick reply ! i enounterd this error t on the command line when i type this command : 
openstack orchestration service list
what i'm asking for is for the heat to work correctly and for this command to show all the engines and to list hte service components to verify the successful launch and registration of each process

Comment: here's a link for what the output of this command should be : 
https://docs.openstack.org/heat/victoria/install/verify.html

Comment: Have you checked the Heat logs?

Comment: where can i find them exactly ?

Comment: Most probably under [/var/log/heat](https://docs.openstack.org/heat/victoria/configuration/logs.html), but it depends on how you configured your cloud.

Comment: these are the output of ls /var/log/heat : 
heat-api-cfn.log  heat-api-cfn.log.1  heat-api.log  heat-api.log.1  heat-engine.log  heat-engine.log.1

Comment: These are the log files, yes. Your mission, should you choose to accept it, is to find messages in these log files that help you understand why the Heat components are not running.

Comment: I accept the mission xD

Comment: These are the errors that i found in the log : 
Unable to validate token: Identity server rejected authorization necessary to fetch token data: keystonemiddleware.auth_token._exceptions.ServiceError: Identity server rejected authorization necessary to fetch token data

 keystonemiddleware.auth_token [-] Identity response: {"error":{"code":401,"message":"The request you have made requires authentication.","title":"Unauthorized"}}

keystoneauth1.exceptions.http.Unauthorized: The request you have made requires authentication. (HTTP 401) (Request-ID: ...)

Comment: i found a typing error in the heat.conf file and fixed it now when i run this command as root : openstack orchestration service list
the output is : ERROR: None